# Oracle adding a subquery in a CTE

Tags: oracle, subquery, common-table-expression

I have the following setup, which works fine and generates output as expected.

I'm trying to add the locations subquery into the CTE so my output will have a random location_id for each row.

The subquery is straight forward and should work but I am getting syntax errors when I try to place it into the 'data's CTE. I was hoping someone could help me out.

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
 employee_id NUMBER(6),
 emp_name VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO employees(
 employee_id,
 emp_name
 ) VALUES 
 (1, 'John Doe');

INSERT INTO  employees(
 employee_id,
 emp_name
 ) VALUES 
 (2, 'Jane Smith');

INSERT INTO employees(
employee_id,
emp_name
 ) VALUES 
 (3, 'Mike Jones');


CREATE TABLE locations AS
 SELECT level AS location_id,
    'Door ' || level AS location_name

    FROM   dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 


 with rws  as (   
select level rn from   dual connect by level <= 5 ), 
   data as (    select e.*,round (dbms_random.value(1,5)
 ) n from employees e)
 select employee_id,
 emp_name,
trunc (sysdate) + dbms_random.value (0, 5)  AS random_date
 from   rws 
 join   data d     on rn <= n
order by employee_id;

-- trying to make this work

  with rws  as (   select level rn from   dual connect by level <= 5 ), 
     data as (    select e.*, loc.location_id = (
      select location_id
      from locations                     order by dbms_random.value()
      fetch first 1 row only
   ),
 round (dbms_random.value(1,5)
  ) n from employees e )
  select employee_id,
       emp_name,
     trunc (sysdate) + dbms_random.value (0, 5)  AS random_date
    from   rws 
    join   data d     on rn <= n
    order by employee_id;
```

Comment: What error do you get, and what version of Oracle are you on? Where in the CTE are you trying to add it, and how? Show the code you run to get the error, as you may be adapting it incorrectly - but if so we can't tell.

Comment: Original post updated with error too. I'm on 19c, I also tried this on livesql and got the same error. I posted the code I'm having an issue with. I'm doing something wrong just not sure what. I also read something about subquery caching will that be an issue in my example. Thanks for your time and expertise

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the subquery column expression, rather than trying to assign it to a [variable] name. So instead of this:

```
  with rws  as (   select level rn from   dual connect by level <= 5 ), 
     data as (    select e.*, loc.location_id = (
      select location_id
      from locations                     order by dbms_random.value()
      fetch first 1 row only
   ),
 round (dbms_random.value(1,5)
  ) n from employees e )
```

you would do this:

```
with rws as (
  select level rn
  from dual
  connect by level <= 5
), 
data as (
  select e.*,
    (
      select location_id
      from locations
      order by dbms_random.value()
      fetch first 1 row only
    ) as location_id,
    round (dbms_random.value(1,5)) as n
  from employees e
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e3dd1c2b39305ef130b613e0c66a038)

But yes, you'll get the same `location_id` for each row, which probably isn't what you want.

There are probably better ways to avoid it (or to approach whatever you're actually trying to achieve) but one option is to force the subquery to be correlated by adding something like:

```
where location_id != -1 * e.employee_id
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b432541ca2d697c9fa715e84713fa8e)

although that might be expensive. It's probably worth asking a new question about that specific aspect.

> I am getting the same location_id for every employee_id, which I don't want either.

The subquery is in the wrong place then; move it to the main query, and correlate against both ID and `n`:

```
with rws as (
  select level rn
  from dual
  connect by level <= 5
),
data as (
  select e.*,
    round (dbms_random.value(1,5)) as n
  from employees e
)
select d.employee_id,
  d.emp_name,
  (
    select location_id
    from locations
    where location_id != -1 * d.employee_id * d.n
    order by dbms_random.value()
    fetch first 1 row only
  ) as location_id,
  trunc (sysdate) + dbms_random.value (0, 5)  AS random_date
from rws r
join data d on r.rn <= d.n
order by d.employee_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=376aa1b2c42f893fc241172843702c52)

Or move the location part to a new CTE, I suppose, with its own row number; and join that on one of your other generated values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are correct I don't want the same location_id for every row. I added the predicate and now I am getting the same location_id for every employee_id, which I don't want either. The purpose of this is to generate a random location_id, which exists in the locations table for each row. I don't care about performance as this is used to create data to stress applications. Any suggestions on how to get a random record for each row or should I proceed with a new question.

Comment: @Beefstu - the correlation gives the same location ID for every row for the same employee ID; but that's because it's in the CTE. If you want a different value for every row in the output then move the subquery to the main query, not the CTE?